# Unconsistent color gradient drawing rectangles/sprites in libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm trying to draw sprites with color gradients using a SpriteBatcher and setting manually the vertex colors to achieve some kind of basic illumination effect without shaders, but I noticed a weird effect in the gradients when only one of the vertex color is different.

It depends on the position of the vertex. If the different color is on the bottom-left or the top-right there's no problem, but in the other two cases there's a weird gradient effect.

To explain better the situation, here's an image.

[image: results]

I generated the top row of squares with the following code:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
Color c1 = new Color(1,1,1,1);
Color c2 = new Color(1,0,0,1);
shapeRenderer.rect(100f, 100f, 30f, 30f, c2, c1, c1, c1);
shapeRenderer.rect(150f, 100f, 30f, 30f, c1, c2, c1, c1);
shapeRenderer.rect(200f, 100f, 30f, 30f, c1, c1, c2, c1);
shapeRenderer.rect(250f, 100f, 30f, 30f, c1, c1, c1, c2);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

This code is generated with a ShapeRenderer, but I get the same result if I do it with a SpriteBatch.

I imagine it's related to the way a rect is drawn internally (based on 2 triangles) but, is there any way to achieve the same result in all the cases? (as the 3rd row of the image)

Something like a different GL draw mode or whatever... ?

Comment: You could maybe get something similar to the third image with a specialized shader, but the only way I can think of would result in a radial gradiant from the corner, not a linear one like you drew. How about simply rotating the sprites 90 degrees if its the top left or bottom right corner you want colored?

Comment: I already thought about rotating but I don't think it's possible since it's not an image, but the colors of its vertices... 
So "rotating" the colors of the vertices will only change the values of the colors, and not the way they are drawn. (i.e. rotating the the top-2 image 90º CW will not result in bottom-2 but in top-3)

Comment: I don't mean rotate the colors. I mean rotate the entire sprite 90 degrees, and select the corner appropriately. For instance, if you want the bottom-1 image, then rotate the sprite 90 degrees counter-clockwise and set the color of the top-right vertex.

Comment: I see... is it possible? 
Anyways, I don't think I can do it because I'm not using Sprites, but TextureRegions and vertices to draw them... so that's why I had in mind the thing about their vertex positions...

Comment: Oh, finally I tried it in the code and it worked!
If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it, but if you don't mind, I'd like to have it a bit more explained for other people to understand. 
Basically what I did is, If I draw the vertices in the next order: V1 V2 V3 V4 but the one with different color is V1, then I draw them in the next order: V4 V1 V2 V3 and assign the different color to V4

Comment: You can go ahead and write the answer. I haven't taken the time to go through the details of changing the vertex order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the thing is, that the drawing depends on the order of the triangles.
If the gradient goes from one vertex of the triangle through its angle bisector there's no problem, but if the color gradient goes along its side, the result is like the top-1 and top-3 squares.

This is due (I think) to the fact a rectangle drawn like

```
1-2
| |
4-3
```

Is actually drawn with two triangles like

```
1-2       1
 \|  and  |\
  3       4-3
```

So, in this order, if the different color is in the vertex 1 or 3, the resulting gradient is weird.

What we can do in this cases is change the order of the vertexes (not its coordinates) to be drawn like this

```
2-3      2-3       3
| |  =>  |/   +   /|
1-4      1       1-4
```

It works just fine as we can see here:

[image: result]